# Tomcat deleting my all uploaded images when ever i re-run application through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am creating web application in Java (Spring framework); using Eclipse  IDE and Tomcat web server.

I have implemented a functionality to upload user images.
Images are uploaded to my application context.

But whenever I re-run the application from Eclipse, Tomcat deletes my all existing images.

Comment: That's probably because you're saving the images where you shouldn't: in the directory where the application is deployed. Save them elsewhere.

Comment: Show the code of your function, please

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat or any web container creates an instance of your project when you run. All the target files and resources are copied to this instance, which is different from actual project location and is the context of the application.

So, when you upload files to the application context they are contained in it only till your server is running.

But if you store images/files in some other location you wont be able to access them till you restart the server.

You can store files in app context and other location (eg. resources) to overcome this problem.

HTH!